# Magento - create a module with simple .phtml template

Tags: magento

I want to create a module with simple .phtml template, that have to be included in the page "cart.phtml" and also in "noItems.phtml"

How can do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple module as shown in [this >>](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) tutorial.. and once you finished the weblog example in the above link, you can take a look at [this link >>](http://www.amicontech.com/blog/magento-hello-world-tutorial/) to create and place a phtml file.

Balan